# Jinja2 use variable from parent template

Tags: python-2.7, jinja2

Image a base template like this:

```
{% set styles = [] %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    {% for style in styles %}
    <link href="{{style}}" ref="stylesheet" type="text/css; charset=utf8">
    {% endfor %}
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to append to the `styles` variable from a child-template, but it will yield "styles is undefined".

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% do styles.append("index.css") %}
```

One solution to this would be to define the `styles` as an empty list when rendering the template from the Python code. But I do not want to add `styles=[]` to every template I render.

Unfortunately, importing doesn't work either. It won't tell you anymore that "styles is undefined", but it simply won't render in the head section of the parent template.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% from "base.html" import styles %}
{% do styles.append("index.css") %}
```

How can this be solved?

PS: You need to add `jinja2.ext.do` to the extensions if you want to test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using blocks

`base.html` would look like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="{{style}}" ref="stylesheet" type="text/css; charset=utf8"> {# all global css includes you need #}
    {% block styles %}
    {% endblock styles %}
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block body %}
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

and then `child.html` would look like this:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block styles %}
  <link href="{{style}}" ref="stylesheet" type="text/css; charset=utf8"> {# all css files you need #}
{% endblock styles %}
```